# How do I pass the id to the controller?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, parameters, controller

I have a textbox that like: `<input type="text" id="10" name="SalesData" />`

I'd like to pass the id back to the controller. Do I need to create a hidden textbox and store the id there? Or is there another way?

Answer (score 2):

A hidden textbox would definitely be best for this scenario

```
<input type="hidden" id="SalesData" name="SalesData" value="10" />
```

and then in your post (or somewhere else like a viewmodel)

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult postedData(int SalesData){
 //TODO: use SalesData
}
```

With a viewmodel:

```
public class SalesVM
{
 public int SalesData { get; set; }
}
```

and then

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ActionNameFromForm(SalesVM model){
 //TODO: use model.SalesData
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you needing to do? Do you need to return both the id and value of the text box to the contoller? If so, i think the hidden field is the way to go.

Comment: Yes, I need to return the id value and the textbox value. They are different values, but related.